# Arbitrary base conversion algorithm for (textually represented) integers

Tags: algorithm, math, pseudocode

I am looking a general algorithm that would convert from one (arbitrary) numerical base to another (also arbitrary) without storing the result in a large integer and performing arithmetic operations on it in between.

The algorithm I am looking for takes an array of numerical values in a given base (that would mostly be a string of characters) and returns the result alike.

Thank you for help.

Comment: Why are you averse to using an in-between large integer? The only other way I see is to write your own division and modulus operators that works on strings of any base, which would likely be both slower and more difficult to implement.

Comment: Because I want to implement it in a custom programming language that does not provide bignum arithmetics, so I would have to roll my own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say it is not possible. For certain bases it would be possible to convert from one string to another, by just *streaming* the chars through (e.g. if one base is a multiple of the other, like octal->hex), but for arbitrary bases it is not possible without arithmetic operations.

If you would do it with strings/chars  *in between* it would be still big integer arithmetic, but your integers were just in a (unnecessary big) unusual format.

So you have just the choice between: Either reprogram arithmetic operations with char encoded numbers, or do the step and use a big integer library and walk the convert(char(base1->bigInt), convert(bigInt->base2) path.

Answer (score 0):

It's computable, but it's not pretty.

Seriously, it'd probably be easier and faster to include one of the many bignum libraries or write your own.